# How can I use fetch in chrome-extension that I change the origin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

When I use fetch,it gets the request origin like this:
Origin: chrome-extension://hhchkohknefpngiknmlkelgmnhokjnef

I want the request origin like this:
Origin: www.xxxxxx.com (the now website page url)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `onBeforeSendHeaders` event.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'Origin')
                details.requestHeaders[i].value = 'https://www.xxxxxx.com';
        }

        return {
            requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders
        };
    }, {
        urls: ["*://www.xxxxxx.com/*"]
    },
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"]);
```

`extraHeaders` option is required for changing changing `Origin` starting chrome 79.

You will need the following permissions in your manifest file:

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://www.xxxxxx.com/*"
]
```

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#implementation