# How can I fetch URLs with credentials in my extension without leaking cookies to user cookeis store?

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So, I'm making web requests in my browser extension with fetch API using `credentials: 'include'`. So far so good, but the cookies that are part of those requests end up polluting the normal user cookie store.

I.e. when I make a request to site X with cookies, the user is suddenly logged into that site without knowing why.

Is there a way to separate the cookies that my extension is using from the ones used for normal browser navigation?

Comment: You can set HTTP `cookie` header internally (only on this single request) using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders event, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58872254).